# Utilizing Async/Await in .NET Console applications breaks when calling Application.Run() or instantiating a WinForms UserControl object

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, command-line-interface, command-prompt

**Background**

Async/Await facilitates responsive applications in .NET by automatically creating a "state machine", allowing the primary thread of an application to remain responsive even while performing blocking work.

Windows Forms, WPF, and ASP.NET (to my knowledge) all incorporate a form of SynchronizationContext (although ASP.NET may have removed this recently; I'm not positive, as I don't work with it.)

I've recently needed to extend a Windows Forms application to also support accepting arguments from the Command Line, and in doing so, discovered Async/Await stopped working. After some number of (almost random) steps into my application, it would either hang or return to an incorrect point, effectively halting.

**SynchronizationContext**

After research, I discovered that under the covers, Async/Await relies on a SynchronizationContext to effectively handle routing machine state (as mentioned above.) What wasn't clear is what happened without a SynchronizationContext: Stephen Toub (on his blog post [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3/)) indicates that Async/Await will execute, but without thread affinity, and that without a SynchronizationContext, Async/Await can end up executing on random threads.

Stephen goes on to explain "AsyncPump.cs", his class for implementing a SynchronizationContext for console applications, and in testing AsyncPump, so far, it's been successful.

**Questions**

1. Stephen's post is from 2012; is there another solution? Perhaps his AsyncPump class has been integrated (and/or modified) into a more recent version of .NET? I would prefer to use an library-designated equivalent, if available, such so that if any changes occur to the under-the-covers implementation of Async/Await, it will automatically be updated as well, like the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext would be.
2. Could I safely use the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext? In Program.cs, I'm determining whether or not I want to instantiate and open a Form, using Application.Run() to do so, which automatically handles setting up a SynchronizationContext for me (as well as message pump, etc.) I tried instantiating a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and setting it on my main thread using SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(), and although this compiles, I encountered the same problems as when I had no SynchronizationContext at all.

I'm looking for the best practice for supporting Async/Await in a console application, because (as far as I can tell) it definitely needs a SynchronizationContext in order to execute correctly.

---

**Edit 1: Adding pseudocode to help illustrate the scenario**

If my program has received more than one argument, I'm assuming that it's been invoked from the Command Prompt, and have created a custom "MyCustomConsole" class which uses P/Invoke to Win32 to call AttachConsole(-1). At this point, I can read/write from the CLI as my program was a Console application. If I haven't received any extra arguments, then I can launch a Windows Form GUI as expected ("Application.Run(new Form1());").

The problem is that the code I end up invoking to perform blocking operations ("RunBlockingOperationsAsync()") is Async/Await to remain responsive, and when invoked via the GUI (through "Application.Run()"), works fine. If I try to call "RunBlockingOperationsAsync" without "Application.Run()", the program deadlocks or jumps to unexpected areas whilst debugging, effectively crashing.

I tried implementing a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext, but that fails in the same manner. However, utilizing Stephen Toub's "AsyncPump.cs" solution corrects the problem (see below.)

There must be a built-in .NET framework piece for this, right? I can't believe Async/Await could be so thoroughly implemented without a default implementation for Console applications. My current understanding is that Async/Await utilization within a Console application without Stephen's "AsyncPump.cs" class (or similar) would not execute properly; effectively, this makes using Async/Await in a Console application unusable as-is by default.

It seems like Console applications should have an equivalent version of "Application.Run()", which initializes an appropriate SynchronizationContext (and whatever else might be necessary—maybe nothing right now.)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading; // <-- Note that System.Threading is required for SynchronizationContext.

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application—NOTE this is the default WinForms implementation for 'Program.cs'.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            MainAsync();
        }

        private static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            // If the application has received more than one argument, assume it's been invoked from the Command Prompt.
            if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Count() > 1)
            {
                using (MyCustomConsole mcc = new MyCustomConsole())
                {
                    SynchronizationContext sctx = SynchronizationContext.Current;   // <-- Initializes sctx to NULL, as at this point in the program,
                                                                                    // there is no SynchronizationContext. It is initialized when
                                                                                    // "Application.Run()" is invoked.

                    // Doesn't work (no SynchronizationContext):
                    await mcc.Run();                                    // <-- If the MyCustomConsole class is invoked without using AsyncPump.cs,
                                                                        // it has no SynchronizationContext, and without it, Async/Await operations can
                                                                        // execute on any thread from the ThreadPool, which causes deadlocks and jumping
                                                                        // (almost at random?) to unexpected parts of my program, which I can only attribute
                                                                        // to the size of the program and including numerous nested Async/Await calls, depending
                                                                        // on what the program is trying to do.

                    // Perhaps instantiate a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and use it?
                    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext = new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext();
                    await mcc.Run();                                    // <-- Also fails in the same manner as above, despite having a SynchronizationContext.
                                                                        // I don't understand why.

                    AsyncPump.Run(async () => { await mcc.Run(); });    // <-- This works. AsyncPump.cs is the custom SynchronizationContext that
                                                                        // Stephen Toub provided in his blog. It not only handles SynchronizationContext,
                                                                        // but sets itself as the SynchronizationContext for the current thread, which
                                                                        // is required for Async/Await to operate with thread affinity.
                }
            }
            else // Otherwise, display the main form and operate with a GUI.
            {
                Application.Run(new Form1());   // <-- Application.Run() instantiates a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext,
                                                // (amongst other things, like a message pump) and this is vital to a proper
                                                // Async/Await machine state that requires thread affinity.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Resolution**

The root of this problem is two-fold: First, a developer using Async/Await should understand that Async/Await's implementation can differ depending on SynchronizationContext; [Stephen Toub does an excellent job explaining here.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/) Understanding that a Console application does not have a specific SynchronizationContext by default, continuations are posted to the ThreadPool. If you debug a Console application, you would find that monitoring SynchronizationContext.Current is NULL.

Second, recognize that (for Windows Forms) Application.Run() sets up a Message Pump and a single-threaded SynchronizationContext. Monitoring SynchronizationContext.Current after Application.Run() would return a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext object. Thanks to @noseratio, I've learned that instantiating a Windows Forms UserControl object will *also* instantiate and set SynchronizationContext.Current to use the new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext, but *only* if it was NULL to begin with.

This explains my problem: The application I'm working on is a Windows Forms application, and when typically started, Application.Run() is used to invoke the Message Pump and also sets up a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext. Async/Await works perfectly. However, when adding on support for CLI, I instantiated an object that derives from UserControl. As soon as I instantiate it, my formerly-NULL SynchronizationContext is now a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext, and now Async/Await continuations are posted to it instead of the ThreadPool—what happens to continuations on the ThreadPool after a new SynchronizationContext is instantiated, I can't say. I experienced erratic program behavior, typically either "await Task.Delay()" calls hanging indefinitely, or control of my application (in the debugger) jumping around seemingly at random. Reportedly, setting (WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false) should prevent automatically replacing a NULL SynchronizationContext with a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext, but in my testing, it was still replaced (and Async/Await still broke.)

I did not test this with WPF, but I expect WPF would behave similarly (and/or developers would face a similar problem.)

There are multiple solutions:

1. The best solution, in my opinion, is to not instantiate a Windows Forms UserControl (or WPF equivalent) when you're executing in CLI mode, if you can help it. Abstract work into it's own classes and leave UserControls (and their equivalents) to View abstractions if possible. This allows Async/Await to run on whatever Synchronization Context your application needs: If Windows Forms, a WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext. If WPF, a Dispatcher (?) SynchronizationContext. If a Console application, it runs on the ThreadPool instead of a SynchronizationContext.
2. Explicitly set your own SynchronizationContext: @Stephen Toub's AsyncPump class; or @Stephen Cleary's AsyncContext class; or either of @TheodorZoulias's solutions worked (in my testing.) There may be good reason for using one of these solutions over #1, for example you may be working on a Console application, but have no choice but to instantiate a WinForms UserControl, or perhaps use a library that does so under-the-hood, unbeknownst to you. I would suggest monitoring SynchronizationContext.Current in various stages of an application if faced with this scenario.

Comment: You mean that the same executable that runs correctly when called without arguments, stops running correctly when called with arguments? Do you call `Application.Start` in both cases?

Comment: There's no way calling the executable with arguments can cause this. Can you post your `Program.Main`?

Comment: *to extend a Windows Forms application to also support accepting arguments from the Command Line* - is it still the same process, or do you need to communicate between multiple process instances?

Comment: I mean `Application.Run()`, not `Application.Start()`.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Sorry, I meant that I use arguments to determine whether or not I attach to a Command Prompt (and use the CLI as the user interface), or if I instantiate a Form and use the GUI as the interface. I edited my post to include pseudocode that I hope helps explain. As you see, I only call Application.Run() when starting the GUI interface with a Form; using the CLI interface has (so far) only worked when utilizing Stephen Toub's "AsyncPump.cs" SynchronizationContext.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I've added psuedocode which I hope better explains the problem.

Comment: @noseratio I'm effectively calling a long blocking method, "RunLongBlockingMethodAsync()", which itself has numerous Async/Await calls nested down throughout it. The only difference is whether or not it's invoked by a Windows Form GUI mouse click, or by recognizing the required arguments. The two don't coexist; I don't have a Command Prompt open alongside the Form(s), for example.

Comment: Console apps don't *normally* need a SynchronizationContext set just for async/await to work.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of synchronization context (or when the default `SyncrhonizationContext` is used), it's often possible for an `await` continuation to run synchronously, i.e., on the same thread where its antecedent task has ended. That can lead to obscure deadlocks, and it was one of the reasons `TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` was introduced in .NET Framework 4.6. For some more details and examples, check out this blog post: [The danger of TaskCompletionSource class](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-danger-of-taskcompletionsourcet-class/).

The fact that `AsyncPump` stops your code from hanging indicates you may have a similar situation somewhere inside `mcc.Run()`. As `AsyncPump` imposes true asynchrony for `await` continuations (albeit on the same thread), it reduces the chance for deadlocks.

That said, I'm not suggesting using `AsyncPump` or `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` as a workaround. Rather, you should try to find what exactly causes your code to hang (and where), and solve it locally, e.g. simply by wrapping the offending call with `Task.Run`.

One other issue I can spot in your code is that you don't wait or await the task returned by `MainAsync`. Because of that, at least for the console branch of your logic (especially without using `AsyncPump`), your program may be ending prematurely, depending on what's going in inside `mcc.Run()`, and you may be letting some exceptions go unobserved.

Comment: I appreciate the advice. In debugging (without a SynchronizationContext), I'm frequently encountering "await Task.Delay()" statements which are then hanging or causing the program to jump back to the previous method (or to a random place in the program.) Given that "await Task.Delay()" is causing the failure (and commenting it is allowing the program to continue), doesn't that seem to point the fault at not having a SynchronizationContext? If I include one (such as AsyncPump), everything appears to be working smoothly—I haven't had any issues, and this code has been in production for months.

Comment: @Justin, it appears there's another sync. context being installed somewhere implicitly, then `Task.Delay` continuation callback gets posted to it. Do you use any WinFroms or WPF objects anywhere in your *console* branch of code? Also, can you spot `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for the continuing advice; the current process does instantiate one WinForms Control, but doesn't display it. It does, however, call an (async Task<bool>) method as part of it, e.g. ("public async Task<bool> DoJob()".) It sounds like you're speculating that this might be related to the Synchronization Context issues—I'll try to remove it and see if that makes any bearing on what's happening. Otherwise, I found no Task.Wait nor Task.Result in the code. Still seems puzzling to me that Task.Delay is where things appear to go awry, but it's probably just coincidence.

Comment: @Justin, it's hard to speculate without being able to repro, but if you do use WinForms controls in a console app, I'd suggest to use them on a separate dedicated thread where you'd install `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` explicitly. For an example, check out my `WinformsApartment` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57626659/1768303).

Comment: You've appeared to diagnose the issue—by porting the code performed in the WinForms class to another non-UserControl-derived class, I'm able to execute everything perfectly without installing or modifying the default SynchronizationContext. Does instantiating a UserControl cause something to happen to the current thread's SynchronizationContext? Or does calling a method as part of that UserControl cause something to happen under the covers?

Comment: @Justin, yes it does. When you instantiate a WinForms control on a thread without s. context (or with the default one), a new instance of `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` gets automatically installed and managed automatically. The way it's done is not straightforward, to say the least (e.g., see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19535147)).

Comment: @Justin, Most likely, you dealing with a case when `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext` is already gone but there're still some pending `await` continuations posted to it. You can manually control its lifetime using `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall` (see the code I linked in my comments above), but even so, if Windows messages are no longer pumped, those continuations won't get executed, and you may end up with a deadlock. The fact that your thread is STA doesn't make it magically pump, you do need to stay on a message loop like the one run by `Application.Run`.

Comment: Thanks for the links—it looks like you've been through a lot with respect to SynchronizationContext, too. You're absolutely right: merely instantiating a WinForms control (a UserControl) does cause the current SynchronizationContext to be initialized (as it was NULL previously, as once again I'm running in CLI mode.) This also explains why (in the presence of an alternative, or already initialized SynchronizationContext), everything works fine. Interestingly, I tried setting SynchronizationContext.AutoInstall = false, including in different methods, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I think this resolves my issue and answers the root problem. I'm going to select your first response as the answer, please feel free to modify it if you'd like—I'm going to update my original post with more details as well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Using Stephen Toub's [`AsyncPump`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps-part-3/) seems sufficient. You could also try starting a standard message loop with `Application.Run()` (without a form), and run your code inside the `Application.Idle` event handler (handled only once). This way you can also interact with UI elements if it's needed for some reason (with a `WebBrowser` control for example).

```
if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Count() > 1)
{
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = async (sender, e) =>
    {
        Application.Idle -= handler;
        using (MyCustomConsole mcc = new MyCustomConsole())
        {
            await mcc.Run();
        }
        Application.ExitThread();
    };
    Application.Idle += handler;
    Application.Run(); // Begins running a standard application message
                       // loop on the current thread, without a form.
}
```

---

**Update:** Another idea is to use a [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher), the object used for thread synchronization in WPF applications. The `Dispatcher` creates automatically a [`DispatcherSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchersynchronizationcontext), so all awaited continuations that lack `ConfigureAwait(false)` will run in the same thread. A reference to the assembly `WindowsBase.dll` is needed.

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

if (Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().Count() > 1)
{
    var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    var invokeTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            await dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
            {
                using (MyCustomConsole mcc = new MyCustomConsole())
                {
                    await mcc.Run();
                }
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        }
    });
    Dispatcher.Run(); // blocking call
    await invokeTask; // await the task just to propagate exceptions
}
```

The `Task.Run` is needed so that the `dispatcher.Invoke` is called from a thread-pool thread, as well as the final shutdown of the dispatcher. Everything else happens in the main thread.

Comment: This is a clever solution, and in my testing, appears to work correctly just as AsyncPump. I especially like this solution because it leverages Application.Run(), so if it should ever change under-the-covers (with .NET or .NET Core/5), the user gets the benefits of those changes automatically, too.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm looking for the best practice for supporting Async/Await in a console application, because (as far as I can tell) it definitely needs a SynchronizationContext in order to execute correctly.

`async`/`await` does not require a context. In the absence of a context, it will use the thread pool context. However, code that *uses* `async`/`await` can certainly make assumptions about threads. In your situation, it sounds as though your code is expecting to run in a single-threaded context. Since it was developed in a single-threaded context (WinForms), that's not surprising.

So the "best practice" for `async`/`await` in a console application is to just run it directly, without a context. But that's not possible in your case because the code you're trying to reuse assumes a single-threaded context.

> Stephen's post is from 2012; is there another solution? Perhaps his AsyncPump class has been integrated (and/or modified) into a more recent version of .NET? I would prefer to use an library-designated equivalent, if available, such so that if any changes occur to the under-the-covers implementation of Async/Await, it will automatically be updated as well, like the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext would be.

It has not been included in .NET.

There are a couple of options for including a message pump. One is to use a Windows Forms UI thread; another is a WPF UI thread. It's been a while since I've done either, but last time I checked the WPF approach was easier to get running, since WPF (unlike WinForms) was designed to allow multiple UI threads.

If you don't actually need a *user interface* (i.e., STA) thread with a message pump, you can also use a single-threaded context of your own. I wrote an [`AsyncContext` type](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/) 
 ([docs](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/doc/AsyncContext.md)) that I have used for this in the past. Unlike the UI contexts, it does not use a Windows message queue. As a single-threaded context, it does have a queue, but it is a queue of delegates.